# What does the symbol mean in the red circle of this picture?

Tags: meaning

This is from an old game. I'm reading this letter and found a symbol. What does it mean?

[image: Book page with a word highlighted]

Comment: Woah!!! That book is damn old!!

Comment: @lee I read it as being a mock-up of an old book, a decorative visual aid to the game in progress. Easy to pick an appropriately archaic font and plant it onto a picture of an old book. Hint: the text stays in a straight line while the book itself curves; the language is contemporary faux-pompous.

Comment: Ohh!! I never got that far 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a symbol--it says "If" in a decorative font. Compare to the later sentence "I founded..." and you'll see that it's just the "I" and the "f" closer together.